# Swagger Java class is not parsing properly

Tags: spring-4, swagger-2.0, springfox

I am using swagger to create API documentation for one of my Spring Rest API project, but the swagger.json file created is having an issue. 
One of my Super class is not getting converted properly.

Library used to implement the swagger is **springfox**. Please find the implementation details below.

*Configuration
EnableWebMvc
EnableSwagger2
ComponentScan*

```
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

This is the class causing the problem

```
public class ListResultModel MODEL extends BaseModel {

}
```

Json Created

```
"schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/RedirectAttributes"}}],"responses":{"200":{"description":"OK","schema":{"type":"string"}},"201":{"description":"Created"},"401":{"description":"Unauthorized"},"403":{"description":"Forbidden"},"404":{"description":"Not Found"}}}},"/admin/migration/vat":{"get":{"tags":["migration-controller"],"summary":"vatMigration","operationId":"vatMigrationUsingGET","consumes":["application/json"],"produces":["/"],"parameters":[{"name":"retailerId","in":"query","description":"retailerId","required":true,"type":"string"}
{"$ref":"#/definitions/**ListResultModel«Item»"**}},"401":{"description":""},"403":{"description":"Forbidden"},"404":{"description":"Not Found"}}}},"/api/items/withoutPictures/{departmentId}/{vendorId}/{status}":{"200":{"description":"OK","schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/**ListResultModel«Item»"}**},"401":{"description":""},"403":{"description":"Forbidden"},"404":{"description":"Not }
{"$ref":"#/definitions/ListResultModel«Lead»"}},"201":{"description":"Created"},"401":{"description":""},"403":{"description":"Forbidden"},"404":{"description":"Not Found"}}}}
```

I am trying to resolve this for a long time and there is no clue how to do it. Can anybody help me please!

Thanks in advance.
Vivek

Comment: what is the error that you're facing? Can you elaborate the issue?

Comment: Hi Bandi Kishore,

Thanks for the Help.

ListResultModel«Item» is not a valid json notation, this should converted in to json format. I am using the generated json to import the API in to Amazone(https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/07/introducing-swagger-importer-easily-import-swagger-api-definitions-into-amazon-api-gateway/) and which is failing because of the below symbol in the json

«
Regards
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

This Got Fixed by the below Thread.

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1283

Regards
Vivek